# Bison one or more occurrences in grammar file

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, bison

My program that needs to be parsed should be of the form:

```html
program   : [declaration]+
          ;
```

Which should mean: The program consists of one or more declarations.
Declaration on its turn is of course defined in a similar way, and so on...

Currently, I'm getting an error on the **+** from the Bison parser.
How do I define the *one or more* condition in a correct way with bison?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One or more:

```
declarations
    : declaration
    | declarations declaration
    ;
```

Zero or more:

```
declarations
    : /* empty */
    | declarations declaration
    ;
```

Answer (score -1):

Apparently,

Bison does not support the + or * symbols to denote these things.

How I solved it:

```html
program     : declarations
        ;

declarations    : declaration declarations
        | declaration
        ;
```

Comment: That's not one or more, that's zero or more. For one or more you want to replace `/* empty */` with declaration.

Comment: This solution is right-recursive, which is not the correct way to use an LALR(1) parser. It should be left-recursive.